# How to select data from Database where between months in the Database?

Tags: sql, database

I have i have 2 input fields that have text and the other dropdown (select option) in html. The user types the  text and select the month from the dropdown (select option) then its submitted to Database. The dropdown have four months March, June, September and December. I want to create a query from database that selects between months like:

```
SELECT * FROM `returndocs` WHERE Year='2020' and Month BETWEEN 'March' AND 'June'
```

My database is: 
[image]

I want to select all the data in the database posted starting from March to June. How do i do that?

Comment: Compare month numbers instead. ('August' < 'June', but 8 > 6.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your drop down put the date instead of month name as value
like

```
03 => March
06 => June
```

then make it 2020-03-01 and 2020-06-01

then run your query with

`SELECT * FROM`returndocs`WHERE Year='2020' and Month BETWEEN '2011-03-01' AND '2011-06-01`'

Answer (score 1):

Since you defined month in `text` type you will need to type all between month manually :

```
SELECT *
FROM `returndocs` 
WHERE Year = 2020 AND
      Month IN ('March', 'April', 'May','June');
```